# Context of MySQL wildcards

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to get a better understanding of the context in which MySQL interprets wildcards, especially the `_` underscore wildcard, which matches exactly one character.  For example, it is a common practice to use snake case in naming databases and tables (e.g. my_sample_database and my_table) and in that context MYSQL does not treat the `_` underscore character as a wildcard.

---

We create table named `my_table` and populate it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table(name, age) VALUES('William', 25);
```

We create table named `my0table` and populate it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my0table
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO my0table(name, age) VALUES('Bart', 15);
```

Sample database has two tables:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_my_sample_database |
+------------------------------+
| my0table                     |
| my_table                     |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We execute the select statement and the DB gives unambiguous results:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+-----+
| id | name    | age |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 | William |  25 |
+----+---------+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM my0table;
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | Bart |  15 |
+----+------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: unambiguous  how`?

Comment: @nbk `my_table` is not confused for `my0table`

Comment: You insertWilliam 25 ijn my_table and your select shows that row and you insert Bart in my0table and the select shiws that result, so what is your problem exactly

Comment: Object names are _never_ expected to be wildcards. Wildcards are only expected in the context of pattern-matching operators, such as `LIKE`.

Comment: It's really very simple - the `_` (underscore character) **is** permitted as a character for a table name **AND/OR** a field_name - it's only when it appears as **DATA**, i.e. **in** a field that you have to escape it for searching - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=244e2f3574352b4e7641753272c14dfe).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see underscore is a wildcard in a LIKE comparison.

If you want the underscore recognizes you need to escape it with `\` ´

But this is basic sql and nothing strange.

Finally it is good practise not to use wildcards reseved words in table names or column names, so you don't get confused and of course all others

> ```
> SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
> WHERE table_name Like 'my_table'
> ```
>
> ```
> | TABLE_NAME |
> | :--------- |
> | my_table   |
> | my0table   |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
> WHERE table_name Like 'my\_table'
> ```
>
> ```
> | TABLE_NAME |
> | :--------- |
> | my_table   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8eac46a44d7de69a0fc43d4639ad25a4)*